# Change data types in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a  csv file that looks like this:

```
table = {'column1': [1,2,3],
         'column2': ['(0.2, 0.02, NaN)','(0.0, 0.03, 0)','(0.1, NaN, 1)']}
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
```

I am trying to access to the array that is stored in "column2", however pandas says that "column2" is an object and therefore if I print df['column2'][0][0], I get '(' instead of "0.2".

How can I change the data type from "object" to numeric values?

I tried this
`pd.to_numeric(df['column2'][0])`
but it didn't work.

Comment: what exactly would be the expected output? Do you just want the first number? All?

Comment: I would like to have all numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` and `ast.literal_eval` won't work as the string `NaN` does not mean anything in Python without context (ofcoruse it's `np.nan` - but the module `ast` isn't aware of that)

So you can change `NaN`s to `None` for a moment, then apply `ast.literal_eval` or `eval` then convert `None`s to `np.nan`:

```
import ast

df['column2'] = df['column2'].str.replace('NaN', 'None').apply(ast.literal_eval).apply(lambda x: tuple(np.nan if val is None else val for val in x))
```

and

```py
df['column2'] = df['column2'].str.replace('NaN', 'None').apply(eval).apply(lambda x: tuple(np.nan if val is None else val for val in x))
```

---

Shorter version would be to replace `NaN` with `np.nan` and give it the Numpy module for context:

```
import numpy as np

df['column2']=df['column2'].str.replace('NaN', 'np.nan').apply(eval)
```

---

If you don't want to use the `ast` module.

```
In [98]: df['column2'][0][0]
Out[98]: 0.2

In [100]: type(df['column2'][0])
Out[100]: tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to `split` the values:

```
df2 = df['column2'].str.strip('()').str.split(',\s*', expand=True).astype(float)
```

Output:

```
     0     1    2
0  0.2  0.02  NaN
1  0.0  0.03  0.0
2  0.1   NaN  1.0
```